# How to bind (authenticate) a user with ldap3 in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap, ldap3

I'm trying to update some code to python3, using [ldap3](http://ldap3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quicktour.html) version '0.9.7.4'.
(https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ldap3)

Previously, I used python-ldap with python2 to authenticate a user like this:

```
import ldap
address = "ldap://HOST:389"
con = ldap.initialize(address)
base_dn = "ourDN=jjj"
con.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3
search_filter = "(uid=USERNAME)"
result = con.search_s(base_dn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, search_filter, None)  
user_dn = result[0][0]  # get the user DN
con.simple_bind_s(user_dn, "PASSWORD")
```

This properly returns `(97, [], 2, [])` on correct password, and raises `ldap.INVALID_CREDENTIALS` on a bind attempt using an incorrect password.

Using `ldap3` in python3 I'm doing the following:

```
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, AUTH_SIMPLE, STRATEGY_SYNC, ALL
s = Server(HOST, port=389, get_info=ALL)
c = Connection(s, authentication=AUTH_SIMPLE, user=user_dn, password=PASSWORD, check_names=True, lazy=False, client_strategy=STRATEGY_SYNC, raise_exceptions=True)
c.open()
c.bind()
```

It's raising the following exception:

```
ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult: LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult - 49 - invalidCredentials - [{'dn': '', 'message': '', 'type': 'bindResponse', 'result': 0, 'saslCreds': 'None', 'description': 'success', 'referrals': None}]
```

I'm using the `user_dn` value returned by python2's ldap search, since this appears to be working in python2.

How can I get this to bind properly using ldap3 in python3?

(*One thing strange, I noticed, is that the ldap3's LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult includes `'description': 'success'`.  I'm guessing this just means response successfully recieved...*)

Comment: Ok tested by using the *wrong* password and found that the resulting Exception is different, `ldap3.core.exceptions.LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult: LDAPInvalidCredentialsResult - 49 - invalidCredentials - None - None - bindResponse - None` and does not contain `'description': 'success'` ... bug?

Comment: I'm running the same commands but getting: `ImportError: cannot import name 'AUTH_SIMPLE'
ImportError: cannot import name 'STRATEGY_SYNC'`

Comment: This was quite a while ago the library may have been refactored, and locations changed...

Comment: Looks like STRATEGY_SYNC -> SYNC

Comment: https://ldap3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#changelog

Comment: Tnx, that worked for me, but now I faced the same issue as you had. see my comment in the answer section

Comment: can you check if you faced it?

Answer (score 25):

I'm the author of ldap3, please set `raise_exceptions=False` in the Connection definition and check the `connection.result` after the bind. You should get the reason why your `bind()` is unsuccessful.

Comment: Thanks!  I checked using `raise_exceptions=False`, but `connection.result` doesn't seem to contain anything useful, that I can tell: `>>> c.result
{'dn': '', 'result': 49, 'message': '', 'description': 'invalidCredentials', 'type': 'bindResponse', 'saslCreds': 'None', 'referrals': None}
`

Comment: Reinstantiating the connection, `c` above with `raise_exceptions=True` still returns `'description': 'success'`, when the given password is correct.

Comment: Note that the `c.result` content is unchanged if the password is correct, or not, unlike the exception result.

Comment: please open an issue on https://github.com/cannatag/ldap3/issues so I can track the problem. I need to know the version of python you're using and the version of the LDAP server you're trying to connect to.

Comment: @cannatag could you please have a look on my question? Thanks!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54225216/convert-ldapsearch-filter-to-python-filter

Comment: @cannatag, can you advise?  Python version: 3.6.6 ldap3 version: 2.7

Comment: Invalid credentials means that you’re sending the wrong credentials to the server

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that your DN doesn't need to escape a comma using backslash `\`.

My organization gives users a CN of "last name, first name", so my DN needed to be "CN=Doe\, Jane, OU=xyz, ..., DC=abc, DC=com"

I realized this by using [Active Directory Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/adexplorer) to navigate to my user object, r-click > view properties to see the distinguished name. I ran into this invalid credential error when using the DN that AD Explorer displays in its Path breadcrumb which omits the escape character.